# I need a query in GAE that return rows that don't contain null, means that are fulfilled

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

```
SELECT * FROM Feedback WHERE text =! None
```

`Nul`, doesn't work either.

It doesn't work... So how should I write this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From GAE documentation:
It is not possible to query for entities that are missing a given property. One alternative is to create a fixed (modeled) property with a default value of None, then create a filter for entities with None as the property value.

You could achieve the same results by:

```
def notnulls():
       return [z for z in db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Feedback') if z.text]
```

This will return a list of Feedback objects where the text field is not None.  Although this does have the extra overhead of loading all Feedback objects first.

Answer (score 2):

Entities with null are not included in the index for that query. You may want to actually store a dummy value like 'None'/'Null' instead. (Ref.  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Restrictions_on_Queries  )

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from Feedback where text > ''
```

Found reference [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-appengine@googlegroups.com/msg05278.html). Note that it's undocumented, so maybe not a very good solution.

Comment: doesnt work too :s the value is not assigned by me. When you create a model and have a property that is not required it remains null, but i dont know what kind of null. in gae terms from what i know that col for that row is not present... because was never assigned a value